# Hitting <Tab> when using vim/bash-completion is doing the same as the <Enter> key

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I have something wrong with my bash-completion when I try to use Vim on a file. I'm using Vim version 7.4.2334. When I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> it has become the same as hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The result is I get "command not found" errors instead of autocompletion when I try to do `vim <filename>`.

I know it's an issue with bash-completion because when I type `complete -r` in the console the issue goes away.

As a commenter pointed out this could be to do with Vim's `operate-and-get-next` code, but I'm not sure what's happening. My `.inputrc` contains `set editing-mode vi` but that has been working for a long time beforehand.

I have dozens of files in `/usr/local/Cellar/bash-completion/1.3_1/etc/bash_completion.d`, but none looks like it's for Vim. Is there a way to figure out which file is causing the issue other than deleting them and re-adding them one by one, or reinstalling bash-completion entirely? Or is this a problem with Vim perhaps?

Comment: Did you changed your `~/.inputrc` recently?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub no - just has `set editing-mode vi`

Comment: Any line containing `operate-and-get-next` on `bash-completion`?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub interesting - after your comment I just realized that there is a line `operate-and-get-next` in my Vim installation, AND that this only happens when I try to use vim on a file, not when I do other things. Last, this is only happening on some directories. For instance, it happens in my `~/Downloads/` directory but not in `/usr/local/Cellar/vim` directory. However - there is no entry for vim in my `/usr/local/Cellar/bash-completion/1.3_1/etc/bash_completion.d` directory.

Comment: You should [edit] your question with context around `operate-and-get-next`